# what kind of serial number is return by Build.getSerial() method

Tags: java, android, serial-number

on some android devices serial number does not match  with phone setting serial number. or dial(*#06#) for example one plus 7t and Samsung devices.

Note:when i use this reflection the problem with Samsung devices is solved and but not working in one plus 7t but for one plus 6t its working fine.

```
public static String getSerialNumber() {
        String serialNumber;
        try {
            Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
            Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class);
            serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "gsm.sn1");
            if (serialNumber.equals(""))
                serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber");

            Log.e("return_ril.serialnumber","My number  "+serialNumber);

            if (serialNumber.equals(""))
                serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.serialno");

            Log.e("return_ro.serialno","My number  "+serialNumber);

            if (serialNumber.equals(""))
                serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber");

            Log.e("return_sys.serialnumber","My number  "+serialNumber);

            if (serialNumber.equals(""))
                serialNumber = Build.getSerial();

            Log.e("return_Build.getSerial","My number  "+serialNumber);

            if (serialNumber.equals(""))
                serialNumber = Build.SERIAL;

            Log.e("return_Build.SERIAL","My number  "+serialNumber);

// If none of the methods above worked
            if (serialNumber.equals(""))
                serialNumber = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serialNumber = null;
        }

        Log.e("return_serialNumber","My number  "+serialNumber);

        return serialNumber;
    }
```